# Fragment via button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I have a fragment defined in my project plus an activity with a button. What I want is to launch the fragment with that button onclick listener, enter a value in the edit text defined in the fragment's xml layout file and press another button2 present in the fragment. Now what I  want is that the button2 return's the text value and open's the activity again. I can then handle what happens to that value.

## Java

```
package com.dreamgoogle.gihf;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Kahinsebhii extends Fragment {
    Button ok;
    EditText number;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kahin, container, false);

        ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        number = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                number.getText();


            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

## Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/kahinbhiedit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok" />

</FrameLayout>
```

## Java file to launch the fragment is some other java file.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like what you need is a `Dialog`. Have a look at the development site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

```
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
```